# java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue executeUpdate() or executeLargeUpdate() for SELECTs

Tags: java, mysql, sql, servlets

I am trying register page, if email exits already it should get alert message, for this below is my some part of the code, i am using `executeQuery` for Select query but still i am getting error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue executeUpdate() or executeLargeUpdate() for SELECTs

java code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxx", "root","root");
            PreparedStatement ps=cn.prepareStatement("select * from Register where email=?");
            ps.setString(1, email);
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next())
            {
                out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
                   out.println("alert('Email already Exists Please Try with New Email');");
                   out.println("location='index.html';");
                   out.println("</script>");
            }
            else{

                   PreparedStatement ps1 = cn.prepareStatement("insert into Register values(?,?,?,?,?)");
                                ps1.setString(1, name);
                                ps1.setString(2, email);
                                ps1.setString(3, mobile);
                                ps1.setString(4, password);
                                ps1.setString(5, conform_password);

                                int i = ps.executeUpdate();
                                if (i != 0) {
                                    response.sendRedirect("index.html");
                                } else {
                                    out.println("Some Thing went wrong. Try Again...");
                                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem has to do with your not closing the first statement used for the select before you try to create another statement for the insert.  But, there is a better way to implement your logic, using a single insert:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Register (name, email, mobile, password, confirm_password) ";
sql += "SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ";
sql += "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Register WHERE email = ?)";

PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, name);
ps.setString(2, email);
ps.setString(3, mobile);
ps.setString(4, password);
ps.setString(5, conform_password);
ps.setString(6, email);

int i = ps.executeUpdate();
if (i == 0) {
    System.out.println("Email already Exists Please Try with New Email");
}
else {
    response.sendRedirect("index.html");
}
```

If the exists clause of the above insert fails, then nothing should be inserted, and the DML row count returned by `executeUpdate()` should be zero.